# Why isnt my nested ng-repeat working

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im not quite sure what is going on with my ng-repeat, but this is what i have.

```
<div ng-controller="DeliveryController">
    <div ng-repeat="stop in Deliveries">
        <div >
            {{stop.stopId}}
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="box in stop.Boxes">
            <div>
                {{box.orderNum}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only thing that is being returned is the first stop.stopId. Im not quite sure if my json is off or what is going on. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what is being returned from my api call.

```
          [
  {
    "stopsInfo": {
      "boxes": [
        {
          "boxID": 1,
          "orderNum": "1",
          "boxNum": "03600029145",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 41.33465,
          "lng": -40.5703457,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-20T00:39:05.323",
          "stopId": 1
        },
        {
          "boxID": 9,
          "orderNum": "2",
          "boxNum": "12345678901",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 41.33465,
          "lng": -40.5703457,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-20T00:39:07.85",
          "stopId": 1
        },
        {
          "boxID": 10,
          "orderNum": "3",
          "boxNum": "01600066060",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 41.33465,
          "lng": -40.5703457,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-20T00:39:09.607",
          "stopId": 1
        }
      ],
      "stopId": 1,
      "contactName": "Justin",
      "companyName": "Ignite LLC",
      "addr1": "123 Main",
      "addr2": "Suite 100",
      "city": "Katy",
      "state": "TX",
      "zip": "77449"
    },
    "signeeId": 1,
    "signee": "Justin",
    "signature": "asdasds",
    "stopId": 1
  },
  {
    "stopsInfo": {
      "boxes": [
        {
          "boxID": 12,
          "orderNum": "4",
          "boxNum": "12345678910",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 43.38928,
          "lng": -40.2342344,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-19T18:29:28.077",
          "stopId": 5
        },
        {
          "boxID": 14,
          "orderNum": "5",
          "boxNum": "123456",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 43.38928,
          "lng": -40.2342344,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-16T16:03:10.777",
          "stopId": 5
        }
      ],
      "stopId": 5,
      "contactName": "Paul",
      "companyName": "Ceremity",
      "addr1": "456 Moutain View",
      "addr2": "Suite 200",
      "city": "Katy",
      "state": "TX",
      "zip": "77449"
    },
    "signeeId": 8,
    "signee": "Paul",
    "signature": "asdasdsadsa",
    "stopId": 5
  },
  {
    "stopsInfo": {
      "boxes": [
        {
          "boxID": 15,
          "orderNum": "6",
          "boxNum": "63938200039",
          "sts": "ORD",
          "lat": 45.32312,
          "lng": -43.2345324,
          "eventDt": "2016-09-14T00:00:00",
          "stopId": 6
        }
      ],
      "stopId": 6,
      "contactName": "Vlad",
      "companyName": "Starbucks",
      "addr1": "789 Riveroak",
      "addr2": "Suite 300",
      "city": "Katy",
      "state": "TX",
      "zip": "77449"
    },
    "signeeId": 9,
    "signee": "Vlad",
    "signature": "asdasdasdasd",
    "stopId": 6
  }
]
```

Comment: use `ng-repeat="stop in Deliveries track by $index"` and `ng-repeat="box in stop.Boxes track by $index"`

Comment: that didnt seem to work

Comment: is that json complete? there is only one stopId (parent) loop btw.

Comment: now complete, there are 3 items

Comment: there you go - https://plnkr.co/edit/G8hrFhkLCZMDB5mKEXwR?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `boxes` array is inside `stopsInfo` object.
Change the loop to:

```
<div ng-controller ="DeliveryController" >

    <div ng-repeat="stop in Deliveries">
        <div >
            {{stop.stopId}}
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="box in stop.stopsInfo.boxes">
            <div>
                {{box.orderNum}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Plunker Sample here](https://plnkr.co/edit/G8hrFhkLCZMDB5mKEXwR?p=preview)

Comment: does the controller have to be in the body tag?

Comment: no..I just copy pasted it from my sample fiddle. You can have it in div as well. Updated the code above - @Monzingo

Comment: yeah i checked the plunker, this is what is being returned

1
1
2
3
5
4
5
6
6

Comment: yeah works, thanks man! Now i just need to wrap my head around it